# MySQL Temporary Table with Group By and Group Concat Extremely Slow

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build out a fairly simple temporary table. The table will end up being 2 columns:

1 A product ID

2 A string of concatenated compliance data in a format that can be consumed later

```html
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE products.compliances_data
      (INDEX product_id_idx (product_id))
     SELECT
        products.product_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('compliance_code', cc.compliance_code, 'compliance_full_name', pc.full_name, 'compliance_web_description_short', pc.web_description_short) SEPARATOR ' - ') as compliances
    FROM products.products products
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products.material_compliance_map cc on products.material_id = cc.material_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products.compliances pc on cc.compliance_id = pc.compliance_id
    GROUP BY products.part_number
```

The table gathers and joins information from 3 tables.

1. The products table is the main source of information. The products table has a column for material_id.
2. The material_compiance_map table. This is a many-to-many table that maps material_id's to compliance_id's
3. The compliances table. This is the table where the actual data is stored that I need to pull from to build out the concatenated object.

The problem is the creation of the temporary table takes 3-4 minutes to run yet only yields about 1.2 million entries which seems incredibly slow.

Running an explain on the select portion of the query yields:
[Explain on select image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Lld.png)

There are only 642 entries in the material_comliance_map so there's not an awful lot of data here that needs to be traversed.

I've tried removing the group_concat and that seems to speed up the query about 33%. The problem seems to revolve around the group by statement.

How can I improve the speed when building this temp table?

EDIT:

Schemas:

material_compliance_map schema

```
'material_compliance_map'
CREATE TABLE `material_compliance_map` (
  `material_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `material_code` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `compliance_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `compliance_code` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`material_id`,`compliance_id`),
  KEY `fk_compliance_id_material_compliances_compliances` (`compliance_id`),
  KEY `fk_material_id_material_compliances_materials` (`material_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_compliance_id_material_compliances_compliances` FOREIGN KEY (`compliance_id`) REFERENCES `compliances` (`compliance_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_material_id_material_compliances_materials` FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `materials` (`material_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

compliances schema:

```
'compliances'
CREATE TABLE `compliances` (
  `compliance_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compliance_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(155) DEFAULT NULL,
  `web_description_short` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`compliance_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `compliance_id_UNIQUE` (`compliance_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `compliance_code_UNIQUE` (`compliance_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

products schema:

```
'products' 

CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `part_number` varchar(27) NOT NULL,
  `material_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `material_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size_code` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `erp_description_1` varchar(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  `erp_description_2` varchar(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_description` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight_lbs` decimal(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_number_prefix` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tight_tolerance` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `part_number_UNIQUE` (`part_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_id_UNIQUE` (`product_id`),
  KEY `fk_material_id_products_materials` (`material_id`),
  KEY `fk_size_id_products_sizes` (`size_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `size_id_idx` (`size_id`),
  KEY `size_id_productsidx` (`size_id`),
  KEY `material_id_idx` (`material_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_material_id_products_materials` FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `materials` (`material_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_size_id_products_sizes` FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`) REFERENCES `sizes` (`size_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1140987 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: You're running full scan on products, then resolving the joins and then, on the resultset, you're grouping. Then, you are creating a group_concat (which is rather expensive) from a json_object. Sure you want a group_concat instead of concat_ws?

Comment: provide your tables schemas for all 3 tables involved

Comment: And `GROUP_CONCAT ... SEPARATOR ' - '` seem weird together with `JSON_OBJECT`. Usually we either need string or json but not mix of both.

Comment: Temporary not always meaning it will run on ram it can also be run on disk.. "If an internal temporary table is created as an in-memory table but becomes too large, MySQL automatically converts it to an on-disk table. The maximum size for in-memory temporary tables is defined by the tmp_table_size or max_heap_table_size value This differs from MEMORY tables explicitly created with CREATE TABLE. For such tables, only the max_heap_table_size variable determines how large a table can grow"  [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)

Comment: @Alex - schemas updated in post - apologies for forgetting that part. as for  the group_concat / json object part, that was just a first pass at getting a format that I could parse afterwards to get an array of objects (this data is all going into elasticsearch documents)

Comment: @Alfabravo - changing to concat_ws seems to have helped a bit. reduced the speed by about 50%. still seems a bit slow though. any thoughts on other optimizations? thanks for the tips!

Comment: to get table schema use `SHOW CREATE TABLE material_compiance_map;` command and put the result as text into your post.

Comment: @Alex - update again. sorry about that!

Comment: why 2 tables are **latin1** and 3rd **utf8** ?

Comment: if this data is for elastic - why do you even need this temp table? From what I remember Logstash can read MySQL directly